# Shell Function To Remove CSV's not working?

Tags: bash, function, shell, unix

I have a few shell commands remove all CSV's from a given directory.  However, when I try to place these in a function they don't seem to work, and I can't figure out why.

```
#works
p=/path/*
for f in $p
do
    if [ "${f: -3}" == 'csv' ]
        then
        rm $f
    fi 
done

#Doesn't work
csv(){
t=$1
for f in $t
do
    if [ "{f: -3}" == 'csv' ]; then
    rm $f
    fi
done 
}

x=/path/*

#doesn't work
csv $x
```

Comment: `$1` will only contain the first filename. Try `t=$@`. For this to work, your filenames can't have spaces in them. It would be better to write your loop like `for f; do ...` which will loop over each input.

Comment: Why not using `find` command? `find /path/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.csv' -delete` (or without `-maxdepth 1` to by *recursive*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
if [ "{f: -3}" == 'csv' ]; then
```

to this:

```
if [ "${f: -3}" == 'csv' ]; then
```

Your function can be written as this:

```
csv() { for f in $1; do [[ "${f: -3}" == 'csv' ]] && rm "$f"; done; }
```

And call it as, **note quotes around `$x`**:

```
x=/path/*
csv "$x"
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash expands your variable reference *before* resolving the shell function call.  The result is that each file matching your glob becomes a separate argument to function `csv()`, but that functions considers only the first one.  This variation should work:

```
csv(){
  for f in "$@"
  do
    if [ "${f: -3}" == 'csv' ]; then
    rm $f
    fi
  done 
}
```

Comment: Note that this version is intended to be called as in your example, *without* quoting the argument.  It also works for multiple explicit arguments.  It can also handle file names containing spaces if you're careful about how you call it.